# Spring security with pages in velocity

Tags: spring, spring-security, velocity

How can I use Spring security when my pages are not in JSP but Velocity? 
is there something like this tag with JSP:

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('frmwrk.user.role.administrator')">
...
</sec:authorize>
```